# Create yaffs2 file system on Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: filesystem

How do I create and mount a yaffs2 file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yaffs/yaffs2 is not yet supported in the mainline linux kernel, so you will need to compile it yourself.

There are detailed directions here : http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Kernel/SimulateNandMtdDevice

You will likely be able to mount a yaffs/yaffs2 file system, but I am not sure you will be able to install into it or boot it with grub.